# Virtualenvwrapper.sh functions not available in bash shell

Tags: python, bash, virtualenvwrapper

I'm doing a new install of virtualenvwrapper, and for some reason after running
virtualenvwrapper.sh it's functions aren't available.

```
$ virtualenvwrapper.sh
creating.....
$ workon
workon: command not found
```

I know that it's running, aside from the successful creation of all the VE files, I've wrapped some of the function definitions in `echo "please get here"` statements and they all get hit.

So: what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh I see, the correct thing to do is:

```
$ source virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

it was on my PATH, and getting run in a subshell, I guess.

Comment: you can add it to your .bashrc so you don't have to manualy source it every time